Reference request: History of the fact that the family of Cauchy-distributed random variables is closed under linear fractional transformations
I asked about this on MathOverflow and it's getting very little attention and no answers.
Suppose a location–scale family of probability distributions has the property that if the distribution of a random variable $X$ belongs to that family and $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb R$ and $ad-bc\ne0$ then the distribution of $(aX+b)/(cX+d)$ is also in that family. Then that is the family of Cauchy distributions. That is proved in "A Characterization of the Cauchy Type" by Frank B. Knight, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 55 (1976), 130–135.
A simpler result is a converse of that: The family of distributions of Cauchy type is closed under that operation.
Which books or papers should be cited to show that simpler proposition, the converse of what Knight's paper says, has been around for a while?

Your statement of the theorem is incorrect, because you can create such families by starting with any distribution and extending it to their transforms under fractional linear transformations.

@whuber Notice I said it's a location–scale family.

I did notice that, but it's irrelevant, because any family closed under fractional linear transformations perforce is a location-scale family.  You seem to overlook Knight's key definition of the "type" of a distribution.

Your last comment seems to imply that if $Z\sim\operatorname N(0,1)$ and $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$ and $ad-bc\ne0$ then $(aZ+b)/(cZ+d)$ has the same distribution as $\mu+\sigma Z$ for some number $\mu$ and some positive number $\sigma.$

But in particular $1/Z$ is not normally distributed; hence its distribution is not a member of the same location–scale family to which $\operatorname N(0,1)$ belongs.

Yes, but $1/Z$ is in the family of fractional linear transforms of Normal distributions (which is a location-scale family).  This would appear to serve as a counterexample to Knight's theorem as related in your post.  The intended assumptions of the (necessity part of the) theorem are clarified in the first lines of Knight's proof and in his equation (2).

How is it a counterexample? The theorem says that IF a location–scale family is invariant under l.f.t.s then it's the Cauchy family. The family of normal distributions is not closed under l.f.t.s and is not the Cauchy family.

I showed a simple construction that creates plenty of location-scale families that are invariant under fractional linear transformations and include non-Cauchy distributions: those are the counterexamples.  The crux of the matter is the specific meaning of "invariant," which has several possible (natural, useful) interpretations.

By a location–scale family I mean you can pick one distribution that is a member of that family, say $f(x),dx,$ and then all of the other members of that family are of the form $f\big((x-\mu) / \sigma \big) , (dx / \sigma),$ and all distributions of that form are members of that family. Thus if one Cauchy distribution is a member of a location–scale family, then all Cauchy distributions belong to that family and no other distributions belong to it. Is that different from what you mean when you refer to a location–scale family? And where would I find these examples of yours?

Take any distribution whatsoever, $F,$ and let $X$ be a random variable with that distribution.  Define a family of distributions by letting $F(,a,b,c,d)$ be the distribution of $(aX+b)/(cx+d)$ for all real numbers $a,b,c,d$ with $ad-bc\ne 0.$  (This is a three-parameter family, btw.)  It is a location-scale family (let $c=0, d=1$).  It is closed under fractional linear transformations.

@whuber But it is NOT a location-scale family (except in that one case).

@whuber : In the case of $Z\sim\operatorname N(0,1),$ the random variable $1/Z$ does NOT have the same distribution as $\mu+\sigma Z,$ regardless of the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma,$ so $Z$ and $1/Z$ do not belong to the same location-scale family.

I see your distinction now, thanks.  I am using a broader definition of a location-scale family: namely, a set of distributions that is preserved under the action of the affine group.  Yours corresponds to the definition of distributional "Type" in Knight's paper.

Searching some, it seems that all hits are somehow related to Peter McCullagh, so maybe ask him? One example: http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~pmcc/pubs/paper28.pdf   One other interesting paper is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.01957
